# MPI error while using MPI_Type_Create_struct

Tags: c++

The code snippet is as follows :

*classA.h*

```
class domain_info{
public:
    long x,y,z;
};
```

***MPI_func.h***

```
#include"classA.h"
# include<mpi.h>
class MPI_func{
  private:
  domain_info *worker_domain;
  MPI_Datatype *MPI_DOMAIN_INFO;
  void build_derived_type1(domain_info *worker_domain,MPI_Datatype *MPI_DOMAIN_INFO);
  public:
  void Mpiinfo (long taskid);
};
```

***MPI_func.cpp***

```
#include"MPI_func.h"
void MPI_func::Mpiinfo(long taskid) {
  worker_domain=new domain_info;
  int rank;
  long i, j;
  build_derived_type1(worker_domain,MPI_DOMAIN_INFO);
}

void MPI_func::build_derived_type1(domain_info*worker_domain,MPI_Datatype*MPI_DOMAIN_INFO){
    int count_DOMAIN_INFO=3;//Number of blocks
    int block_lengths_DOMAIN_INFO[3];
    MPI_Aint displacements_DOMAIN_INFO[3];
    MPI_Datatype typelists_DOMAIN_INFO[3];
    block_lengths_DOMAIN_INFO[0] = 1;
    block_lengths_DOMAIN_INFO[1] = 1;
    block_lengths_DOMAIN_INFO[2] = 1;
    typelists_DOMAIN_INFO[0] = MPI_LONG;
    typelists_DOMAIN_INFO[1] = MPI_LONG;
    typelists_DOMAIN_INFO[2] = MPI_LONG;
    MPI_Aint start_address_DOMAIN_INFO;
    MPI_Aint fin_address_DOMAIN_INFO;
    displacements_DOMAIN_INFO[0] = 0;
    MPI_Get_address(&(worker_domain->x),&start_address_DOMAIN_INFO);
    MPI_Get_address(&(worker_domain->y),&fin_address_DOMAIN_INFO);
    displacements_DOMAIN_INFO[1] = fin_address_DOMAIN_INFO - start_address_DOMAIN_INFO;
    MPI_Get_address(&(worker_domain->z),&fin_address_DOMAIN_INFO);
    displacements_DOMAIN_INFO[2] = fin_address_DOMAIN_INFO - start_address_DOMAIN_INFO; 

    MPI_Type_create_struct(count_DOMAIN_INFO,block_lengths_DOMAIN_INFO,displacements_DOMAIN_INFO,typelists_DOMAIN_INFO,MPI_DOMAIN_INFO); 
    MPI_Type_commit(MPI_DOMAIN_INFO);
}
```

main.cpp

```
# include"../include/MPI_func.h"

using namespace std;
int main(int argc, char **argv){
    //Some MPI Variables
    int taskid; //Rank of the proc
    int numtasks; 
    int is_error;// variable for storing the error code 
    //Initializing the MPI Workspace
    is_error  = MPI_Init(&argc,&argv);
  is_error |= MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD,&numtasks);
  is_error |= MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD,&taskid);
    if (is_error != 0){ 
        fprintf(stderr,"Error in initializing MPI Workspace\nExiting...");
        MPI_Finalize();
        return -1;
    }
    //Initializing MPI  
    MPI_func *obj=new MPI_func;
    obj->Mpiinfo(taskid);
    MPI_Finalize();
}
```

I am getting the following error when I run Mpiinfo in my main_file @ runtime

"An error occurred in MPI_Type_create_struct reported by process [2270035969,0] on communicator MPI_COMM_WORLD

MPI_ERR_TYPE: invalid datatype

MPI_ERRORS_ARE_FATAL (processes in this communicator will now abort,and potentially your MPI job)"

Could someone please help me with this. Thanks..

EDIT: Solved...

I used

```
MPI_Datatype MPI_DOMAIN_INFO;
```

instead of

```
MPI_Datatype *MPI_DOMAIN_INFO;
```

and also changed args to &MPI_DOMAIN_INFO

maybe it needed to be instantiated before use... A better explaination will be helpfull thanks...

Comment: unable to tag mpi :(

Comment: change this line MPI_Init(&argc,&argv); to MPI_Init(NULL,NULL); and test. I have no problem with NULL,NULL

Comment: MPI_Init(NULL,NULL) also gives me the same error

Comment: Check your MPI Version. I think the problem is internal with in MPI

Comment: mpicc -v gives me.   Configured with: --prefix=/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr --with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
Apple LLVM version 9.0.0 (clang-900.0.38)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin17.2.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin